# Disable Increasing Speaker Volume (for Child)

Tags: 12.04, sound, speakers

My child always uses very high speaker (built in) volume in Ubuntu 12.04. How can I fix it to a certain lower level so that he can not increase the sound anymore?

Comment: I don't know of any simple configuration option(s) for that. I know that it's possible but non-trivial and probably tedious, as you'd have do modify the configuration files of the two involved audio subsystems ALSA and PulseAudio. This will probably take a few hours of research and trial and error. I'm willing to point you in the right direction, if this sounds like a viable solution to you.

Answer (score 0):

Type in Terminal :-  `sudo alsamixer`
and you can customize the volume.

Comment: And then?? can you explain how to Disable Increasing Speaker Volume??

Comment: @KasiyA Alsamixer sets the system default volume. You can reduce the speaker volume but I noticed it works same as the GUI.

Comment: The OP wants **Disable increasing volume**. user(his child) can not able to increase volume.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the setting menu? Unclick 'Allow louder than 100%' this reduces the volume to some extent.
[image]